# Project Server 2013 - Sharepoint, permissions lost after publish

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

Since a month ago , when someone publish a project, the current permissions are lost.

I have been doing test creating new projects and they don't have permissions for the users that are configurated as project managers, but if I update the user (example: Changing RBS) the permission is created in the project site , but this permissions is deleted after a publish.

Currently version is 15.0.4569.1506.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you publish the Project Plan it triggers automatic job which syncs the permission with Project Site. By default user who creates the Project is the owner of Project Plan and he will have access to Project Web App Site. If you want any other user to access Project Plan you can simply add that user to Project Team via Build Team option and Publish the changes.

**Note: - it's not mandatory to assign task to user who is part of build team.**